# Group data together and retain groupings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  price    quantity  mtmvalue
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ------   --------  ---------
J1   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   10.00      10      100.00
J4   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   5.00       5       25.00
J2   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   10.00      10      100.00
J3   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   5.00       10      50.00
```

I need to group data together by Deal,Commodity, and startdate so that my dataframe looks like this:

```
ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  price    quantity  mtmvalue
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ------   --------  ---------
J1   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   10.00      10      100.00
J2   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   10.00      10      100.00
J3   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   5.00       10      50.00
J4   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23   5.00       5       25.00
```

I am doing this which will create two groups, but I want it in one dataframe:

```
df.groupby(['Deal', 'Commodity', StartDate'])
```

How would I retain the groupings in the original dataframe?

Comment: Maybe you need just sorting instead of groupby. Do you want to do any calculations on the groupby object?

Comment: @sdawar yes I do have calculations on the groups. I calculate a result which is then merged onto the original dataframe. The only issue is that the original dataframe data is in random order and not grouped how it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)?

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Deal', 'Commodity', 'startdate'], ascending=False)

   ID  Deal Party         Commodity startdate  enddate  price  quantity  mtmvalue
0  J1  Sell     J  (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23  01Feb23   10.0        10     100.0
2  J2  Sell     J  (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23  01Feb23   10.0        10     100.0
1  J4   Buy     J  (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23  01Feb23    5.0         5      25.0
3  J3   Buy     J  (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23  01Feb23    5.0        10      50.0
```

Note: There is not enough information here to correctly rank J3 ahead of J4.

Comment: For the note, those are just mock IDs. the IDs in my dataframe are long strings so the order does not matter. As long as the data is grouped  together by those columns then that will satisfy my case.